# Hierarchical modules with selectable targets using scons

Tags: scons

I want to be able to selectively build a hierarchical source tree based on common build patterns defined at the top-level. The source tree is comprised of a number of different modules, sometimes at different levels within the hierarchy, something like this:

- Large Module Package

  - Submodule Package A

    - Module A1
    - Module A2
  - Submodule Package B

    - Module B1
- Small Module Package

  - Module C1
  - Module C2

Each module may depend on any number of other modules (without cycles, of course).

Each module needs to be able to activate a selection of a set of template targets, defined at the top-level, that will look for certain source files and build certain outputs. For example, the `Library` template target will simply build the current module's shared library. The `UnitTest` target will make sure all upstream dependencies have their libraries built, look for the unit test source, build and then run a unit test executable.

The goal is to have each module to have its own encapsulated SConscript file that would list a) its dependencies and b) the names of the top-level targets that should be enabled for it.

Ideally, I'd like to ensure these targets can be built in a manner similar to this:

```
scons ModuleA1_UnitTest
```

How can I set up scons to do this for me, particularly in a way that is friendly to adding new modules?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the [SCons Alias()](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/c4457.html) function to do this.

The nice thing about the Alias() function (better description in the [SCons man pages](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html)) is that you can assign several targets to the same alias, like this:

***Module A SConscript:***

```
libAtarget = env.Library(target='a', src=libASrcFiles)
env.Alias('libraries', libAtarget)
```

***Module B SConscript:***

```
libBtarget = env.Library(target='b', src=libBSrcFiles)
env.Alias('libraries', libBtarget)
```

The scope of the alias is project-wide, meaning it can be added to in different SConscript scripts. Im not sure if you will be able to define an alias in the root SConstruct (for the creation of your *template targets*) without specifying the target.

Assuming you correctly list the libraries etc needed by the binaries, you shouldnt have to do anything special regarding dependencies on other modules, as SCons should manage that internally.

Comment: My concern with this approach is that it results in a fair amount of code duplication. It's not a big issue just for the library target, but as the targets get more complex (packaging and distributing result files, invoking tests, storing and forwarding log files, etc.), this will result in a lot of nearly identical code in different files. It was my hope that I could store the common logic associated with these targets in top-level files, and just a few of the parameters to them in the Module-specific ones.

Comment: @professional_yet_not_trackable you could create Python functions to do all of the common stuff, and pass lib names, alias names, etc as parameters.

Comment: Ah, yes. It looks like Environment.AddMethod was the missing piece for what I wanted to do.